# Audio in Video Editor but not in rendered output

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, audio

I'm editing a video with a separate MP3 audio track. Everything works fine when I preview playback within the video editor, but the rendered videos have no audio. They have an audio track with the proper settings, but no actual audio.

My render settings are configured for "FFmpeg Video", with h.264 video and AAC audio. These same settings worked with another video I rendered recently, but not for this one.

If I try to use *Render* > *Render Audio...*, Blender seems to work on it for a few seconds and then crashes. The output audio file ends up 0-bytes, no matter the container.

[image: Render settings in Blender, set to "FFmpeg video", "Matroska" container, "H.264" video encoding, and "AAC" audio encoding.]

I tried dropping in a random OGG audio file, but to no avail. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It should work, so I think it's better if you upload a short version of your file, with a little piece of audio and video.

Comment: as Josh said, please upload your blend file -> https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The solution comes from Richard Antalik, at developer.blender.org

Enable *Sequencer* in *Output Properties > Post Processing* panel.

In Blender 3.0 the *Output Properties* (tab) is where you define the size of your output, where to output your file to, encoding for video and audio, etc. You will also find in the same tab the *Post Processing* panel with compositing and sequencer check boxes. Put a check on the *Sequencer*.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same answer more than once, if the questions are the same instead vote to close them as duplicates, thanks.

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos There are a lot of questions that could be solved with what Richard Antalik has posted to me. The solution could be a correct answer. I think that this could be helpful. The questions are not all the same, not duplicates. How would the questioner find an answer to his question if you eliminate the questions?  I would ask that you as a moderator might consider being a bit more moderate. I would appreciate more conversation with you. A moderator's task surely takes a lot of your time and talent, thank you.  Atentamente       Cheers